# Contagem de dados por faixa apresenta resultado errado

Tags: c, algoritmo

> A prefeitura de uma cidade fez uma pesquisa entre seus habitantes, coletando dados sobre o salário da população. A prefeitura deseja saber: a) Número de pessoas com salário maior que R$ 2000,00.Numero de pessoas com salário menor que R$ 2000,00O final da leitura de dados se dará com a entrada de valor -1 para o salário.

Acredito que não esteja totalmente errado, mas quando eu executo ele, o primeiro `if` meio que passa por cima do outro `if`, na hora de contabilizar o numero de pessoas contabiliza somente o do primeiro `if` que eu coloquei.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int contador1=0,contador2=0, salario;

main()

{
    do{
       printf("Digite o seu salario (para cancelar digite -1): ");
       scanf("%f", &salario);

       if(salario>=2000){
            contador1=contador1+1;
       }

       if(salario<2000){
            contador2=contador2+1;
       }
    }while(salario>0);

   printf("Pessoas com salario maior de 2000.00 reais: %d \ne menor de 2000.00 reais: %d\n",contador1, contador2);

   system("pause");
   return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem vários problemas no algoritmo.

Um deles é que o tipo de dado usado para salário é um inteiro e depois pede para digitar um tipo de ponto flutuante. Tem que compatibilizar os dois. Se compilou está usando um compilador bem ruim, sugiro procurar outro. De fato há outros problemas no código que o compilador não deveria deixar passar.

Na verdade `float` nem é o tipo certo para algo como salário, mas é aceitável para exercício, só [saiba que esse tipo tem problema com valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

O exercício pede para sair ao digitar -1, e isso não está sendo verificado. Assim que digita esse número deve encerrar o algoritmo de repetição imediatamente, não pode continuar executando outras partes dele porque daria um resultado final equivocado por contar o que não deve (o -1).

Depois você deve apenas verificar se o valor está em uma das faixas para estabelecer o contador. A outra faixa é exatamente oposta à primeira, então basta fazer o contador no `else` desse bloco de comparação. O `else` serve justamente para isso.

O `while` pode ser simplificado quando a condição de saída está dentro dele (ele pode ficar como se fosse infinito já que a saída será manual).

Os nomes das variáveis poderiam ser mais significativos e o incremento poderia ser simplificado.

O enunciado é ambíguo (na verdade é errado estritamente falando), seu código considerou que se for igual à 2000 considera como se fosse maior, mantive isso.

Melhorei mais algumas outras coisas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int abaixo2000 = 0, acima2000 = 0;
    while (1) {
        float salario;
        printf("Digite o seu salario (para cancelar digite -1): ");
        scanf("%f", &salario);
        if (salario == -1) break;
        if (salario < 2000) abaixo2000++;
        else acima2000++;
    }
    printf("Pessoas com salario maior de 2000.00 reais: %d\ne menor de 2000.00 reais: %d\n", acima2000, abaixo2000);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nXXcrB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CountRangesc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CountRanges.c).

Comment: Ah, sim, entendi! muito obrigado mesmo pela resposta, ficou bem mais claro algumas coisas que eu ainda não sabia.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz o seguinte:

```
scanf("%f", &salario);
```

você está usando a flag `%f` que é de um número Float.

Você deve usar a de inteiro decimal, visto que a variável é um inteiro:

`scanf("%d", &salario);`

Mais sobre as flags possíveis usadas [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) (em inglês).

Comment: Nossa.. esqueci disso, pq na verdade eu fiquei TANTO tempo tentando resolver isso que eu acabei mudando tantas coisas, mudei variaveis, adicionei, tirei.. e acabei esquecendo disso, muito obrigado! acho que eu nao teria percebido o erro.